# How do I remove tab bar when user navigates to another screen?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

My goal is simply to remove my app's tab bar whenever the user navigates to a specific screen, so that I have more space available.

Currently, my storyboard looks like this:

[image]

Whenever the user clicks a button they will be taken to another screen, which is the last screen in the sequence. My goal is to simply remove the tab bar, but keep the navigation.

If I use a `show detail` segue, then it will remove the tab bar but also the navigation, which is something I don't want.

This is the final screen (but it still has tab bar):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

All you need it to set `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true` on the view controller you want it to be hidden on. insert in `viewDidLoad()`

You can also set this in the storyboard of the children view controllers

[image]

Comment: This approach will adjust the objects like label, or images from tab to no tab. It's like it happen in split second

Answer (score 4):

You can even set the property `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` equal to `true` on your `DestinationViewController`. You can do it in your `prepareForSegue` method override.

```
if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? YOURVIEWCONTROLLER {

    vc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
}
```

In this way, if the ViewController should need the bottom bar in other cases, it'll be shown

Answer (score 1):

You can write `prepareforsegue` like below,

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender    {

segue.destinationViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

// Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
```

**Swift:**

```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    segue.destinationViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true

}
```

So in destination view controller tabbar will not shown.

According to your question you can implement in `FirstTableViewcontroller` and tabbar will not visible in `TaretViewController`.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: This approach is a little bit weird because it will adjust the current label. For example firstView has tab and then when goes to another screen it will adjust the size of the labels , images and so on. It's like it happen in split second

Answer (score 0):

hide in  viewWillDisappear

self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;